# How to stop removing <p> & <br> tags in wordpress editor without any plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I have use WordPress editor but I don't want to remove all extra `<p></p>` and `<br>` tags.

How to stop removing p & br tags in wordpress editor without any plugins

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I tried to solve same issue and found this https://www.leighton.com/blog/stop-tinymce-in-wordpress-3-x-messing-up-your-html-code

A solution that works
After making do with a setup that was marginally better than the out-of-the-box way of working for 6 months, we found that the JavaScript modification method above no longer worked due to changes in the core TinyMCE.js file introduced with recent versions of WordPress 3.x, and that there had been an easy, clean and highly effective solution under our noses all the time that essentially replicates our old JavaScript method but using PHP and WordPress hooks to change the parameters TinyMCE uses when it is initiated.

This short bit of PHP code should be put into your themes functions.php file

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
    $opts = '*[*]';
    $initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

… and voila! no more messing with your source code when saving or switching views

Comment: It is not working. I need to overide without any plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution how to stop removing `<br>` tags or double (`<br><br>`) line breaks.

1. Make changes to your file `/wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/functions.php`

Add 2 lines to the top of your functions.

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
```

This will turn off `wpautopop` function.

2. Make changes in file `/wp-includes/formatting.php` in function `wpautop`.

   A) Change `function wpautop( $pee, $br = true)` to `function wpautop( $pee, $br = false)`.

   This will additionally turn off `wpautopop` function from all places.

   B) Change `$pee = preg_replace('|<br\s*/?>\s*<br\s*/?>|', "\n\n", $pee);` to

   ```
   $pee1 = $pee;
   $pee = preg_replace('|<br\s*/?>\s*<br\s*/?>|', "\n\n", $pee);
   $pee = $pee1;
   ```

   This will prevent the system from removing double `<br>` tags. (I know the code is strange but simple `//$pee` doesn't help here because of `?>` tag).

   C) Change `$pee = preg_replace("/\n\n+/", "\n\n", $pee);` to `//$pee = preg_replace("/\n\n+/", "\n\n", $pee);`

   This will prevent the system from removing multiple line breaks.

   D) Change this:

   ```
   $pee = preg_replace('!<p>\s*(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)!', "$1", $pee);
   ```

   to that:

   ```
   //$pee = preg_replace('!<p>\s*(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)!', "$1", $pee);
   ```

   This will prevent the system from removing line breaks after the opening or before the closing block element tag like `<div>`, `<article>`, etc.

   E) Change this:

   ```
   $pee = preg_replace('!(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)\s*</p>!', "$1", $pee);
   ```

   to that:

   ```
   //$pee = preg_replace('!(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)\s*</p>!', "$1", $pee);
   ```

   Pretty the same: This will prevent the system from removing line breaks after the opening or before the closing block element tag like `<div>`, `<article>`, etc.

   F) Change this:

   ```
   $pee = preg_replace('!<br />(\s*</?(?:p|li|div|dl|dd|dt|th|pre|td|ul|ol)[^>]*>)!', '$1', $pee);
   ```

   to that:

   ```
   // $pee = preg_replace('!<br />(\s*</?(?:p|li|div|dl|dd|dt|th|pre|td|ul|ol)[^>]*>)!', '$1', $pee);
   ```

   This will prevent the system from removing `<br>` at the end of the block.

   G) Change this:

   ```
   $pee = preg_replace('!(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)\s*<br />!', "$1", $pee);
   ```

   to that:

   ```
   //$pee = preg_replace('!(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)\s*<br />!', "$1", $pee);
   ```

   This will prevent the system from removing `<br>` after an opening or closing block tag.

Hope it will help! And read comments in this file – they will help you to understand what you need to turn on or turn off.

Comment: It's awesome you provided such a detailed answer.  Just a question - will all that work get undone on Wordpress core update?

Comment: It will most likely be undone on update soner or later.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem and i've been using the no breaking space tag to 'fix' it.  The content in my text tab of the editor will look something like this:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras luctus placerat risus, vel suscipit nibh cursus sed. Donec sit amet urna maximus enim malesuada eleifend et sit amet nibh. 
 
Fusce accumsan justo id orci suscipit pulvinar. In feugiat dolor id blandit luctus. Phasellus placerat enim felis, quis elementum risus ultricies sagittis.

Comment: Please, format your question to make your example look like example.